# Resolving View and ViewModel using IOC

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, unity-container, prism

I have a user control implementing the following interface:

```
public interface IView
    {
        object DataContext { get; set; }
    }
```

..and it's corresponding view model implementing the following interface:

```
 public interface ICertificationViewModel
    {     
        string NumOfCertification { get; set; }
    }
```

I have another service called a NavigationService implementing the following interface:

```
 public interface INavigationService<TView,TViewModel>
    {
        void ShowView<TView,TViewModel,T>(T model) where T:class;
    }
```

I'm using unity and I need to put together a new(transient) view and viewmodel whenever the ShowView method on navigation service is called. I cannot inject the View and ViewModel as constructor dependencies(since new instances should be created), and I don't want to take the service locator route(i.e calling unity inside ShowView to resolve the view and viewmodel). Is there a way I can solve this issue using unity or anything else? I have searched everywhere and I cannot find a definite answer.I'm using Prism and .NET 3.5. I would also like to keep this a bit generic so any views and view models could be resolved using the NavigationService ShowView method.

Can you please help with a solution?

Comment: [This link from Prism's tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861(v=pandp.40).aspx) can be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The **Prism** library provides a **RegionNavigationService** that controls *Navigation* among *Views*. **RegionNavigationService** implements **IRegionNavigationService** and a ***RequestNavigate()*** method is defined. You can resolve *Navigation* for any *View* registered in the specified *Region* (It wouldn't make sense to *Navigate* through *Views* in different *Regions*).

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides navigation for regions.
/// </summary>
public interface IRegionNavigationService : INavigateAsync
{
    ...
}
```

INavigateAsync:

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides methods to perform navigation.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Convenience overloads for the methods in this interface can be found as extension methods on the 
/// <see cref="NavigationAsyncExtensions"/> class.
/// </remarks>
public interface INavigateAsync
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initiates navigation to the target specified by the <see cref="Uri"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="target">The navigation target</param>
    /// <param name="navigationCallback">The callback executed when the navigation request is completed.</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Convenience overloads for this method can be found as extension methods on the 
    /// <see cref="NavigationAsyncExtensions"/> class.
    /// </remarks>
    void RequestNavigate(Uri target, Action<NavigationResult> navigationCallback);
}
```

If you have some custom pre and post *Navigation* work done in the ***ShowView()*** method, you can implement **INavigationAware**, which defines ***OnNavigatedTo()*** and ***OnNavigatedFrom()***, on the *Views* or *ViewModels* involved.

To see how these methods work, the following **QuickStart** uses ***OnNavigatedTo()*** method in order to read and set any context parameters on the new navigated *View*:

- [View-Switching Navigation QuickStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430881%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)

**INavigationAware** documentation:

- [View and ViewModel participating in Navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx#sec9)

If this doesn't help, it would be useful to know the expected behavior the ***ShowView()*** method
would have.

Regards.